# Read Amazon S3 URI image address to Amazon Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I started trying Amazon Rekognition to compare faces called from a Lambda execution. my model starts from user uploading an image and S3 will send an event to trigger a lambda that directly fetches the two closest images in the bucket to compare faces, but I can't read the image from the address S3's URI to Lambda to compare faces which has to create a test to read two images from S3 up. Do you guys have a way to get the URI address from S3 to Lambda to compare faces?

This is my test.

```
{
    "sourceImage": "source.jpg",
    "targetImage": "target.jpg"
}
```

This is the main program

```py
import json
import boto3
    
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    dump = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    sourceImage = dump['sourceImage']
    targetImage = dump['targetImage']
    
    bucket='your_name'
    
    client = boto3.client('rekognition')
    faceComparison= client.compare_faces(
        SourceImage={'S3Object': {'Bucket':bucket,'Name':str(sourceImage)}},
        TargetImage={'S3Object': {'Bucket':bucket,'Name':str(targetImage)}}
    )
    res = {
        "faceRecognition": faceComparison
    }
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use URI to access objects on s3 unless it is a public object/bucket. There are 2 alternatives you can use:

1. You can use the [download_fileobj](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj) method from boto3 to get streamingbody of the object and pass that to your function.
2. You can use [download_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file) method to download the file to /tmp location in lambda and then give path of that file to your function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a Lambda function that reads objects from Amazon S3, use the Amazon S3 API to read the object bytes and DO NOT use an Object URI.

This AWS tutorial performs a very similar use case:

***The Lambda function reads all images in a given Amazon S3 bucket. For each object in the bucket, it passes the image to the Amazon Rekognition service to detect PPE information. The results are stored as records in an Amazon DynamoDB table and then emailed to a recipient.***

So instead of comparing faces, it detects PPE gear. Its implemented in Java, but you can port it to your programming language. It will point you in the right direction:

[Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_ppe)

Comment: In Lambda can I get an image in S3 Bucket, to compare with each image in DynamoDB that I have through Rekognition?